# Objective-C struct definition and modification gives error 'Expression not assignable'?

Tags: ios, objective-c, struct, variable-assignment

I have been reading other similar questions but those solutions either don't fit our don't solve the problem I have in my hand. My code is actually quite simple, I don't know how I should do what I want. Ok:

In .h file I have:

```
struct MyState{
    float quantizer;
    BOOL isOpen;
};

@interface ... {
    ...
    struct MyState myState;
}

@property (nonatomic,assign) struct MyState myState;
```

And in .m file, I have write and reads such as:

```
@synthesize myState

...
self.myState.isOpen = TRUE;
if(self.myState.isOpen)
    self.myState.quantizer = myQuantizerValue;
```

Now, XCode won't accept accessing with '.' operator. It says 'Expression is not assignable'. I tried changing myState to a pointer and converted my read/write's to user '->' operator like:

```
self.myState->isOpen = TRUE;
```

It then gives a runtime error on the assignment. What should I do to access and modify these properties in a simple way? I wanted to use a struct constructor just to avoid declaring and synthesizing separate variables for each property in  MyStruct.

Comment: @matt I use TRUE and FALSE instead of YES and NO. Are not they same on the eyes of the compiler?  And I don't understand what's the problem with synthesizing a variable that has the type of the struct I define? Every other variable I have (including simple nonatomic, assign BOOLs) are synthesized at the beginning of my .m file. I thought I would synthesize myState variable (which is of type MyState) just like them. Is there a problem with it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is the same reason why you can't assign into the `size` of a view's `frame` property. It's a limitation of Objective-C. See the discussion of this issue at the end of [this section of my book](http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch05.html#_properties). As I explain there, you have to fetch the struct property value into a variable, change the member of the struct, and assign back into the property:

```
struct MyState s = self.myState;
s.isOpen = YES;
self.myState = s;
```

Basically this is because the "dot" in `self.myState` is completely different from the "dot" in `myState.isOpen`. The first one is an Objective-C call to the `myState` *method*, and returns a struct. The second one is a C access to a struct member.

The alternative is simply not to use an Objective-C property in the first place: just access the instance variable directly:

```
self->myState.isOpen = YES;
```

But of course you can't do that from some other class without making this instance variable public...

Comment: Thank you for a clear answer. I couldn't get my head around the other examples. In my case, I am updating the struct at each iteration of a for loop. Making double assignments in there seems pretty overhead :/ Anyway, thanks it works!

Comment: What if I declare s in global scope in the .m file? Can I use, edit and access it directly then (and use s as my state keeper)? This appears to achieve what I want directly, much better than fetch&write.

Comment: If you are concerned about efficiency, then don't use an Objective-C property. Just access the instance variable directly: `self->myState.isOpen = YES;` Now you are talking pure C.

Comment: No, it is a limitation of C, not of Objective-C. And it has nothing to do with Objective-C'c dot notation. I explain that in my book.

Comment: @matt I am quite confused about how I should declare the variable public. Can you please update your answer and show how to declare and synthesize this myState variable in .m and .h files, so that    self->myState.isOpen = YES;  is a valid statement?

Comment: @matt By the way, my consideration is not efficiency. The reason I want this is that there is a UI element in my application which toggles the state. In another for loop, I continuously check the state and if it is toggled, I save the state to the struct and break out of the loop. Later on another UI trigger, I continue the loop from where it was left off. Therefore, if I introduce a dummyState variable to this system, there is a chance that my toggled state can be overwritten inside the for loop.

Comment: @batilc `self->myState.isOpen = YES` _is_ a valid statement. self can always directly access self's instance variables. And this solves the fetch-and-replace problem: you are now assigning directly into a member of the struct. What I'm pointing out in my answer is that one object is not normally able to see a _different_ object's instance variables. They are private (actually, protected) by default. The whole point of Objective-C properties is that they help you put public accessor methods in front of private instance variables.

Comment: @matt Thank you for your explanations! I finally managed to configure the behavioral model I needed. I know I am asking basic questions but this objective-c is pretty new and obfuscating for me :)

Comment: @batilc "but this objective-c is pretty new and obfuscating for me" Clearly. You're doing all this C stuff but you don't seem to actually know C. I don't grasp why you're doing that. Why haven't you started with Swift instead? That's what it's for - to make life easier.

Comment: @matt Well, I do know C and C family quite well, but I don't know what exactly objective-c brings into the equation. I am not sure what self actually is, and I haven't grasped the whole concept. Therefore, I really don't know how much I am writing C-like code here. I don't see where my code is "pure C" or "not so pure C".

Comment: @matt The reason I am working on directly objective-c is that I have recently switched to JS and been working on a phonegap project for ios. I am modifying a plugin I have, so I don't know if I have another option here. I have just looked at a few basic tutorials on objective-c for working with I have. If you know a good tutorial that you can recommend, I would be glad to inspect on.

Comment: I already linked you to my book. It explains how Objective-C is built on C.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do what you're trying to do. You can't make a struct a property and assign a value to one of the elements of the struct. Instead you have to set up a local variable that contains the same struct, configure it, and then assign the entire struct to the property:

```
MyState aStruct;

aStruct.isOpen = TRUE;
aStruct.quantizer = myQuantizerValue;

self.myState = aStruct;
```

Note that you have the same problem with the frame and bounds properties of a view, for the same reason.

A CGRect is a struct. The view has a bounds CGRect property.

You can't say

```
myView.bounds.origin.x = 70;
```

Instead you have to say;

```
CGRect bounds = myView.bounds;
bounds.origin.x = 70;

myView.bounds = bounds;
```

Edit: Crap, it looks like Matt and I gave substantially the same answer but he was quicker on the send button.

Comment: Thanks for the hand though! It's always good to have multiple confirmation on things.

Answer (score 1):

To access the struct directly like you wanted to do since the "dot" in self.myState is objective C and the "dot" in myState.isOpen is a 'C' member struct, use an underscore instead.
_myState.isOpen = TRUE;